# How to give a kick to a pie chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The pie chart:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc} 
\usepackage{ifthen} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand{\slice}[5]{ %% use 5 arguments here   
\pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}   
\let\midangle\pgfmathresult

% slice %% I changed !10 to !30 to get darker color   
% use the fifth argument #5 to pass the color     
\draw[thick,fill=#5!30] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;

% outer label   
\node[label=\midangle:#4] at (\midangle:1) {};

% inner label   
\pgfmathparse{min((#2-#1-10)/110*(-0.3),0)}  
\let\temp\pgfmathresult   
\pgfmathparse{max(\temp,-0.5) + 0.8}  
\let\innerpos\pgfmathresult   
\node at (\midangle:\innerpos) {#3}; }

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\newcounter{a} \newcounter{b} 
%% -------------- use the new variable \c to pass the color 
\foreach \p/\t/\c in {20/type A/red, 
   4/type B/blue, 11/type C/red,
   49/type D/green, 16/other/yellow}   {
    \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
    \addtocounter{b}{\p}
    \slice{\thea/100*360}
           {\theb/100*360}
           {\p\%}{\t}{\c}  %% here we use the fifth variable 
           }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But how to make it look a bit more awesome just to give it a kick?

Comment: Please mark code sections with `{}`  (indent 4 spaces) not as a quote `>` "awesome" isn't really a useful description of the intended output, unless you have an actual problem to solve this question is likely to get closed as unclear or too broad

Comment: What @DavidCarlisle said. Also, this code also does not compile for me.

Comment: The code above does not use the [`pgf-pie`] package, so I modified your question slightly. What changes would you like?